# YouTube embed showing device support option

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, embed

I embed Youtube videos in my angular app using two directives which make use of the YouTube Iframe API. The first loads the library async

```
   angular.module('myApp')
    .service('youTubeService', function($rootScope, $window) {
      var self = this;
      self.ready = false;
      $window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
          self.ready = true;
          console.log("Youtube service ready");
          $rootScope.$broadcast('youTubeServiceReady', true);
      };
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = '//www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    });
```

I then embed the video using the javascript library

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('youtube', function (youTubeService) {
    return {
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              var player;
              var playerReady = false;
              var playerState;
              var callback;

              var carouselScope = element.parent().parent().scope();

              function createPlayer() {
                  player = new YT.Player(element[0], {
                      height: attrs.height,
                      width: attrs.width,
                      videoId: attrs.youtube,
                      playerVars: { 'start' : attrs.starttime, 'end' : attrs.endtime, 'origin': 'https://', showinfo: 0, modestbranding: 1 },
                      events: {
                          onReady: function () {
                              playerReady = true;
                              // if (callback !== null) {
                              //     callback();
                              // }
                          },
                          onStateChange: function (event) {
                              //console.log("Time:" + getCurrentTime() + ", Duration:" + getDuration() );
                              playerState = event.data;
                              if (playerState === YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
                                 carouselScope.play();
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  });
              }

              if (youTubeService.ready) {
                  createPlayer();
              } else {
                  scope.$on('youTubeServiceReady', function () {
                      createPlayer();
                  });
              }
    ...
```

This was working for months up until yesterday but now I get the following video as my embed in all desktop browsers as documented here

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6098135?hl=en-GB

My problem is I can't figure out what I should be changing because as far as I understand the iframe api is the correct one. Does anyone know what I should be changing?

Comment: The service and directive code looks fine; however, it looks like you're loading in a youtube ID that comes via an attribute on the directive (attrs.youtube). How is that attribute set ... is it manual? Or is it an ID that is fetched from the data API? If its the latter, chances are that source is using the now-retired V2 API.

Comment: Our entire site is broken thanks to this exact problem :( The only difference with our code, is that `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` is put outside the angular app, and a promise periodically checks for a globally set ready bool.

Comment: Also, and even more bizarre, is that some of the embeds work within our site with the same exact code.

Comment: @jlmcdonald - thanks for pointing me in the right direction. We were getting the video in our id using a rails gem which was using the V2 api. When we switched over to a new gem it all worked fine again. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 0):

So we were having the exact same issue with our site.

It turns out that our client, which uses code very similar to yours above is functioning correctly. Our problem ended up being the way in which we were adding videos and video meta data to our database.

This might not be your issue, but we were using

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/<video id>?v=2&alt=json
```

to add videos to our system. As this turns out to be a deprecated endpoint, we had to upgrade to the v3 system which is explained here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

Comment: We were using the right endpoint but we were obtaining the video ids using a Rails gem which was communicating with the v2 api. Glad you got your site working again!

Comment: Mind sharing some snippet on what you used to replace this call to get metadata ?